# Table with php and html

Tags: php, html

i try to do a table in html with php and i was a little problem with 2 notice(are the same notice) aparently doesnt break my code but i want to know how i can resol the notice

and more important i cant delete a row i dont know why...maybe my code is bad...someone can help me; i leave the code here

the errors are:

Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\ejercicios\02_calculadora_basica\Tablas_new.php on line 40

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\ejercicios\02_calculadora_basica\Tablas_new.php on line 40

is in this part:list($nam,$dep,$sex)= explode(chr(9),$linea);

```
<?php
$val1=$_GET['dato1']; 
$val2=$_GET['dato2'];
$val3=$_GET['dato3'];

if($val1!=''){ 
   $fp = fopen("datos.txt", "a");
   fwrite($fp,$val1.chr(9).$val2.chr(9).$val3.chr(13).chr(10));
   fclose($fp);
}
?>


<html>
     <head>
     <style>
         table,td,tr,thead{
              border-collapse: collapse;
              border: 2.5px solid black;
              text-align: center;
         }

     </style>
     </head>
  <body>
     <table id="Funcion">
        <tr>
            <td>#</td>
            <td>Nombre</td>
            <td>Depenbdencia</td>
            <td>Sexo</td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        $fp = fopen("datos.txt", "r");
        $cont=0;
        while(!feof($fp)) {
            $linea = fgets($fp);
            list($nam,$dep,$sex)= explode(chr(9),$linea);
            //echo($nam .chr(9) .$dep .chr(9).$sex ."<br>");
            $cont++;
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo($cont); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo($nam); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo($dep); ?></td>
                <td><?php echo($sex); ?></td>
                <td><input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
        }
        fclose($fp);
            ?>  
        <script>
        function deleteRow(r) {
            var i = r.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
            document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(i);
        }
        </script>
  </body>

</html>
<br>
<br>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Tablas funcionarios</title>
<style>
body{
    background-image: url("1336135496617.png");
    color: white;
}
table,tr,td{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 2.5px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <br>
    <form method="get">
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <td> nombre</td>
                <td><input typ"text" name="dato1" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>dependencia</td>
                <td><input typ"text" name="dato2" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>sexo</td>
                <td>
                    <select name="dato3"  >
                        <option >femenino</option>
                        <option >masculino</option> 
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td align="right"><input type="submit" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>

    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: *"with 2 notice(are the same notice)"* - What are they, only you know.

Comment: You shouldn't use text files as your database without first considering race conditions; also, you could use `fgetcsv()` and `fputcsv()` to your advantage if a database is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2x instances of `typ"text"` where it's missing both the "e" and an equal sign.

Change both `typ"text"` to `type="text"`

That is the reason for the 2 notices.

As for this:

```
document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(i);
```

You don't have an id called "myTable" but you have once called "Funcion" `<table id="Funcion">`

---

**Edit:**

Replace:

```
$val1=$_GET['dato1']; 
$val2=$_GET['dato2'];
$val3=$_GET['dato3'];
```

With:

```
if(isset($_GET['dato1']) && !empty($_GET['dato1']) ){
   $val1=$_GET['dato1'];
}

if(isset($_GET['dato2']) && !empty($_GET['dato2']) ){
   $val2=$_GET['dato2'];
}

if(isset($_GET['dato3']) && !empty($_GET['dato3']) ){
   $val3=$_GET['dato3'];
}
```

**You can also do this:**

Rename your submit button to:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
```

and do:

```
if(isset($_GET['submit'])){

    if(isset($_GET['dato1']) && !empty($_GET['dato1']) ){
       $val1=$_GET['dato1'];
    }

    if(isset($_GET['dato2']) && !empty($_GET['dato2']) ){
       $val2=$_GET['dato2'];
    }

    if(isset($_GET['dato3']) && !empty($_GET['dato3']) ){
       $val3=$_GET['dato3'];
    }
} // brace for if(isset($_GET['submit']))
```

Yet, if GET is not required, I suggest you change it all to a POST method.

Comment: thanks :) now i can delete my rows but my notce still bother me

Comment: @user3690136 You're welcome. Reload my answer and look under my **Edit** near the bottom, see if that makes the notices go away.

Comment: @user3690136 Ok, I saw your edit about the offsets. I'm trying to fix that and can't pinpoint where the error is.

Comment: @user3690136 I've been at it for an hour and I couldn't fix it, sorry. I tried.